# Mesh manipulation very slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

My program receives a Mesh at runtime. The mesh can be made of over 200k vertices.
I need to reverse it (inside-out). I reverse the indices, but I also need to invert the normals. So far, I used this loop:

```
Vector3[] newnormals = new Vector3[mesh.normals.Length];
for (int i=0;i<mesh.normals.Length;i++)
{
    newnormals[i] = -mesh.normals[i];
}

revMesh.normals = newnormals;
```

where "mesh" is the original Mesh, and of course "revMesh" is the reversed one.
I don't know why, but this loop is incredibly slow. it takes many seconds on my i7. If I substitute it with

```
revMesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

the execution time goes down to under 100 ms.…

Why is my routine so inefficient? Is there some way to speed it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe getting `mesh.normals[i]` in each iteration makes it slow, try:

```
Vector3[] newnormals= revMesh.normals;
for (int i=0;i<newnormals.Length;i++)
    newnormals[i] = -newnormals[i];
revMesh.normals = newnormals;
```

> **Note:** To make changes to the normals it is important to copy the normals from the Mesh. Once the normals have been copied and changed the normals can be reassigned back to the Mesh.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-normals.html

You could also do: (didn't test but i think it works)

```
using System.Linq;
revMesh.triangles = revMesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: Now you where a bit faster ;) It is still questionable though if this will reduce the time from "many seconds" down to "under 100 ms" ...

Comment: @derHugo Just saw your comment on the question seconds after I posted answer.

Comment: @RufusL no. Like the most such values in Unity it is not a field but a **property**. Therefore you can for example not do something like `mesh.normals[0] = new Vector3(x,y,z);` but always have to copy the entire array, modify it and write the entire array back as state in `Note: To make changes to the normals it is important to copy the normals from the Mesh. Once the normals have been copied and changed the normals can be reassigned back to the Mesh.` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-normals.html)

Comment: Performance skyrocketed! execution time plummeted to 95 ms. RecalculateNormals() was about 65 ms, and I still don't know how can it be so fast….but 95 ms is absolutely acceptable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, I'll take your word for it. Still not sure what difference it being a property makes, though - isn't a reference type always a reference type? In "normal" c#, if I have a class `Foo` with an `int[] Bar {get; set;}` property, and I assign `int[] x = fooInstance.Bar;`, then modifying `x[n]` will also modify `fooInstance.Bar[n]`. It must be that the property getter returns a copy of the array instead of a reference.

Comment: @RufusL exactly ;)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that reading `mesh.normals` does not directly access the array. Unity creates a copy of that array and passes you the copy. You read `mesh.normals` twice per loop iteration, so for a mesh with 200k normals you will be creating 400k copies of that array. That may run very slowly, indeed.

It will be *much* faster to ask Unity for one copy of the array, do your work on it, and then pass the data back to Unity once that's done.

Unity's internal classes have a few properties that return fresh copies each time they are read. It's always good to check the manual if you're not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is clear. I’m an old asm programmer, and I have sometimes trouble understanding what happens under the hood with hL languages like c#, but now that you explained it I understand where the trouble was. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kefren It's an insightful question. Given your knowledge, that performance issue must have seemed very odd!